# Find Index from C# List<List<string>>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<List<string>>` and it appears like this:

```
[0]
    [0]Elephant 
    [1]26
    [2]Thailand
[1] 
    [0]Elephant 
    [1]40
    [2]Thailand
[2] 
    [0]Ant
    [1]2
    [2]Australia
[3] 
    [0]Camel Red hump
    [1]1
    [2]Nigeria
```

I want to find the index where the word `Camel` is found ex: 3.

```
int index= animals.FindIndex(r => r.Contains("Camel"));
```

However, the above code returns -1. How can I solve this ?

Comment: The outer list seems to contain structured data. Can't you create a class?

Comment: You've described some code and said that it fails. How should we know why? We can't see the failing code. **Show us the code**.  Give us a short program *that runs* that we can look at; if you do that, either the bug will become obvious to you, or it will be obvious to us. But without the code, we can't tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I have come far with this method. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: foreach top level item, `.FindIndex()`.

Comment: You can use nested `for` loop to scan the entire list to find your index and break once you found it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not reproducible:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var animals = new List<List<string>>()
        {
            new List<string> { "Elephant", "26", "Thailand" },
            new List<string> { "Elephant", "40", "Thailand" },
            new List<string> { "Ant", "2", "Australia" },
            new List<string> { "Camel", "1", "Nigeria" }
        };
        int index= animals.FindIndex(r => r.Contains("Camel"));
        Console.WriteLine(index);
    }
}
```

That prints 3, as expected. **You are doing something wrong in code you have not shown us**.   Show us the code that is failing.  **Take the code above that I just wrote, which is a complete program that you can cut-n-paste and execute, and modify it so that it demonstrates your bug**.  By doing so, you will either find the bug, or you will write a program where it is clear to others what the bug is.

---

UPDATE: The problem is not as stated. **In the future, please write questions that describe the problem you actually have**.  That saves everyone involved from wasting time looking at the wrong problem.

The real problem is:

```
    var animals = new List<List<string>>()
    {
        new List<string> { "Elephant", "26", "Thailand" },
        new List<string> { "Elephant", "40", "Thailand" },
        new List<string> { "Ant", "2", "Australia" },
        new List<string> { "Camel red hump", "1", "Nigeria" }
    };
```

And we wish to find item 3 based on the query string "Camel".

Here's how you attack this problem. First, you solve it for **a single string**:

```
string test1 = "Foo Bar Blah";
string test2 = "Camel red hump";
```

What do we want?  We want to know if "Camel" appears in a string. That is done with `string.Contains`:

```
Console.WriteLine(test1.Contains("Camel")); // False
Console.WriteLine(test2.Contains("Camel")); // True
```

All right.  We can solve the problem for a single string.  Now solve the problem for a list of strings:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "Ant", "2", "Australia" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "Camel red hump", "1", "Nigeria" };
```

We wish to know if the predicate `string.Contains("Camel")` is true for **any** member of `list1` or `list2`.    So use `Any`:

(Remember to add `using System.Linq;` to use the `Any` sequence method.)

```
Console.WriteLine(list1.Any(s => s.Contains("Camel")); // False
Console.WriteLine(list2.Any(s => s.Contains("Camel")); // True
```

Great, we now have a predicate that applies to lists of strings.  Now we wish to apply that to a list of lists of strings:

```
var index = animals.FindIndex(
  list => list.Any(
    s => s.Contains("Camel"))); 
// Prints 3
```

You see what I did there?  **The methodology you should use for attacking problems on sequences-of-sequences is to solve the problem on individual elements first, then extend that solution to sequence-of-elements, and then extend that solution to sequence-of-sequence-of-elements, and so on**.  Build up from simple problems to harder problems.

Now, all that said, `Any` is probably the wrong predicate to use. If you have an animal `new List<string>{"Canada Goose", "123", "United States"}` and an animal `new List<string>{"Wolverine", "4567", "Canada"}` you run the risk of searching for `Canada` and finding the wolverine when you are looking for the Canada goose.  You should probably not be representing this data as `List<List<string>>` in the first place. You *should* be doing this:

```
class Animal
{
  public string Kind { get; }
  public int Size { get; }
  public string Country { get; }
  public Animal (string kind, int size, string country)
  {
    this.Kind = kind;
    ... and so on.
```

Now you can say:

```
 var animals = new List<Animal>()
    {
        new Animal("Elephant", 26, "Thailand"),
        new Animal("Elephant", 40, "Thailand"),
        new Animal("Ant", 2, "Australia"),
        new Animal("Camel red hump", 1, "Nigeria")
    };
```

And now your test is:

```
int index = animals.FindIndex(a => a.Kind.Contains("Camel"));
```

which is much easier to understand. **Build types that represent concepts in your business domain**. That will allow you to build programs that look like the *concepts* in your code, and not the *mechanisms*.

Comment: I have updated my post. Instead of `Camel` the string is `Camel red hump`.  I am using the code `int index= animals.FindIndex(r => r.Contains("Camel"));` but it returns `-1`. But when I search for the full string which is `int index= animals.FindIndex(r => r.Contains("Camel red hump"));`, it prints the correct index. Can you help me sort this out ?

Comment: @Illep: That's a totally different problem than the one you described, so it is no wonder that it has a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to know if part of the string is present in some item of the List?

```
int index = animals.FindIndex(r=>r.Any(x=>x.Contains("Camel")));
```

Just to explain a little, your code was searching for an exact match, but you don't have the same string. So this answer search for the index of the first List (`FindIndex`) which at least one element (`Any`) contains (`Contains`) the string `Camel`. Note that the code is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

@EricLippert answer is correct as usual, but let me try to refactor your code a bit more.

You have a list of lists of strings, and the sublist always contains:

- On index `0`, an animal
- On index `1`, an Id
- On index `2`, a country.

If this is the case for every entry on the list, then this is way better abstracted with a class:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Animal { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can replace the `List<List<string>>` into something more useful and typed: `List<MyItem>`.

This way, you can use linq properly, for example:

```
var item = list.First(i => i.Animal.Contains("Camel"));
```

Using this strategy, you do not need to get the item index and after that get the other values.

Comment: Hah, I just made the same suggestion. Great minds think alike!